# Classifying representations of GL(n): what's a good reference?

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

What's a good reference for the classification of finite-dimensional algebraic representations of $\mathrm{GL}(n,k)$ when $k$ is an arbitrary field of characteristic zero?   For $k = \mathbb{C}$, Fulton does it using Young diagrams in Chapter 8 of his book *Young Tableaux*.   Other treatments for $k = \mathbb{C}$ are easily found online, e.g. this blog article:

- David Speyer, [How to write down the representations of GL(n)](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/07/08/how-to-write-down-the-representations-of-gl_n/).

But I want a citeable, and I hope easily understood, reference that does it for any field of characteristic zero!